# Laravel default selection on form when loading page

Tags: php, laravel

I have a select tag on a form, and I want to populate a default option, this default option will be the one that is searched. I can get it through something like `$_GET` but it does not work in my case, as I am looping through and getting all the values from the database.

```
  <select name="location">
  <option value="" placeholder="Choose Location" disabled selected>Choose Location</option>
  @foreach ($availableCities as $cities)
  <option value="{{$cities}}">{{$cities}}</option>
  @endforeach
  </select>
```

I am looking for a way to show a default selection when loading this form, I tried doing like this

```
<select name="location">
      <option value="" placeholder="Choose Location" disabled selected>Choose Location</option>
      <option value="<?= $_GET['location]" echo 'selected' ?>><?=$_GET['location']</option>
      @foreach ($availableCities as $cities)
      <option value="{{$cities}}">{{$cities}}</option>
      @endforeach
      </select>
```

But this does not work, it shows a value which is not from the search. Any ideas how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to do something like

```
@foreach ($availableCities as $cities)
<option value="{{$cities}}" {{ $cities == $_GET['location'] ? 'selected' : '' }}>{{$cities}}</option>
@endforeach
```